# Как монтировать ISO-образы на Windows 7?

Tags: windows, поиск-программ, образ, iso-образ

Многие крупные скачиваемые обновления поставляются в виде образов для болванок - файлов формата ISO. Прожигать диски, чтобы с них устанавливать обновления, - это пустая трата расходников, потому что после обновления диски уже не нужны - получается, что это диски однократного использования. Вопрос в том, как правильно монтировать образы в Windows, какие для этого существуют встроенные или устанавливаемые инструменты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Daemon tools (Lite-версия бесплатна), alcohol и множество других ,есть кстати и утилита от майкрософта, но не помню, как называется... Да и в конце концов можно просто открыть архиватором - 7-zip'ом, например. )

Answer (score 2):

Давно использую [Virtual CloneDrive](//www.elby.ch/products/vcd.html).

Бесплатная, работает хорошо, позволяет создавать несколько виртуальных дисководов и умеет автоматически подключать образ после перезагрузки.

Имеется русский язык (и не только). Впрочем, он там не особо нужен.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше UltraISO не найти. Он не только монтирует, ну и сжимает папки в ISO. А еще плюс такой, скачали *.MDF (*.mds не качайте, он не нужен), переименовываете в ISO и монтируете! На счет Daemon tools вы должны иметь ввиду, что NOD32 ругается что там **вирус**, и приходится добавлять исключения вручную. Потому от использования этой программы я навеки отказался. Обратитесь ко мне, дам скачать через свой сервер напрямую!

Comment: Я скорее поверю, что лучше отказаться от пользования NOD'ом (в пользу Касперыча и Dr.Web'а), чем от Daemin Tools

Answer (score 1):

[XP: Small, Free Way to Use and Mount Images (ISO files) Without Burning Them](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/620/xp_small_free_way_to_use_and_mount_images_iso_files_without_burning_them/).

В отличии от демона и алкоголя не нужно перегружать комп. Маленькая, простая, шустрая.

Answer (score 0):

От себя порекомендовал бы https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImDisk
Компактная и многофункциональная утилита. Абсолютно бесплатная и позволяет работать с образами разных форматов. Часто использую ее для эмуляции дискет.
Скачать:
http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk